# Newlines in textarea not interpreted in text from database

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax, iframe

I've got text that is 'ajaxed' in a textarea which is inside an iFrame (the source is from the same website).

If I set the content directly as an argument of one of the functions I tried it works fine and newlines get interpreted, but not when using the variable holding the data coming from the MySQL database.

I've tried multiple ways as I've seen in a few posts on stack but nothing works.

```
let content = $('#myFrame').contents(); // Get the content of the iFrame

let description = response.description; // Ajax data : text

content.find('#description').val('foo\r\nbar'); // Works
content.find('#description').html('foo\r\nbar'); // Works
content.find('#description').text('foo\r\nbar'); // Works

content.find('#description').val(description); // Doesn't work
content.find('#description').val(String(description)); // Doesn't work
content.find('#description').html(description); // Doesn't work
content.find('#description').html(String(description)); // Doesn't work
content.find('#description').text(description); // Doesn't work
```

As per request I'm adding more information however I can't put all the HTML, there's a lot of stuff.

The table settings in MySQL for that particular row :

Name : description

Type : text

Collation : utf8_general_ci

A php script uses mysqli to retrieve the data :

```
$description = $row['description'];
$arrayAr['description'] = $description;
```

Then sends the data to jquery as a JSON :

```
echo json_encode($arrayAr);
```

The ajax part with jQuery :

```
function ajaxStuff(link, num) {
    $.ajax ({
        url: link,
        type: "POST",
        data : {id: num},
        dataType: "json",
        cache: false,
        success: function(response) {
                let content = $('#myFrame').contents();
                // the rest of this code is in the snippet above
        }
```

The HTML, the actual page and the page called with the iFrame both have UTF-8 charset :

```
<iframe src='../forms/form2.php' 
id='myFrame'
frameborder='0'
width=''
height='800'
scrolling=''
></iframe>";
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Can you add html code too?

Comment: Thank you @RayeesAC. I've added more information. Please do let me know if anything else could be useful.